# A way to use 'on click' twice in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have 4 rectangles in the main agent, which represents different sites (locations). These sites have information related to them individually, and when combined, their values are also combined. Currently, my model is making a list of all the possible combinations i.e. 1 and 2; 1, 2 and 3; 1 and 3 etc. My aim is to select the combination myself rather than generate all of the combinations.

I am currently using 'on click' to take the model to a separate view area. What I want is to click on these rectangles to make a combination, but I am wary that if I use the 'on click' it will conflict with the view area. Is it possible to do both of these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you take advantage of the `Controls` palette, the one with all the GUI elements.

There isn't really one answer to your question. It will be your choice of designing the user interface. You could for example add a button in the corner of each site and that button would take you to the view area instead of using `on click` and use the `on click` for initial selection of multiple sites.

Or, you could add two radio buttons at the top of the screen, one to click for selecting multiple sites and the other for switching between view areas. These buttons would be linked to a variable the value of which would change between 0 and 1 depending on which button was clicked last. In that case, your code in the `on click` could be a conditional statement such as:

```
if( variable == 0 )
viewArea.navigateTo();

else
< code to add site to selection >
```

Finally, if you really need to use the `on click` twice, the best way to do that is to create a variable called count for example of type `int`. And in the `on click` field, make its value increase by 1 on the first click. And similarly to the above code, add an if statement based on which the 2nd time you click would depend on that variable. For example:

```
if( count == 0 )
{
  < code to add site to selection >;
  count++;
}

else
viewArea.navigateTo();
```

That way, the first click would allow you to select the site, the 2nd click would navigate you there.

I know this is not a straightforward answer, but the question can be approached from multiple angles. This at least should give you ideas.